# Static IP broke internet connection

Tags: internet, static-ip

I tried to set up a static IP, i got myself a static IP, but now the internet connection is not working. I did these steps:

```
- ifconfig, i wrote down information about my internet. 
- sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces 
- i typed this: auto lo eth0 iface eth0 inet static address 192.168.1.120 gateway 192.168.1.2
```

Can someone help me? Thanks! :D If you know how to reset the settings, i would like to know how.

Comment: Why did you set IP address this way and not in Network manager?

Comment: Seems like you did not specify the netmask.

Comment: Do you know how het a working Static ip?

Comment: Instead of making a new question, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/729681/internet-connection-not-working-static-ip) your first one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

192.168.x.x cannot be a static IP to the "internet" those are only internal IP addresses. We will need more info to help you out. Are you behind a router?

Comment: It's not my router but i have access to it. So yes i think

Comment: Wow i just fixed my internet, but i still dont have a working Static IP

Comment: THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER. Delete this and wait to post a comment.